# Указание класса хранения по умолчанию?

Tags: c++, c++11

Можно ли задать некую область, в которой все определения функций, будут считаться принадлежащими заданному классу или пространству имен?

Сейчас при определении приходится явно указывать класс хранения:
void A::func()

```
struct A
{
void func();
void func2();
};

void A::func(){}
void A::func2(){}
```

А вот как было бы удобнее:

```
class_storage : A
{
    void func(){}
    void func2(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя. 
Можно определять функцию при объявлении со всеми вытекающими.